# How to report the results of a binomial logistic regression?

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, interaction, binomial-distribution, lsmeans

I am currently trying to understand how temperature influences the hatching success (no of eggs hatching) of two species of insect. As a result I have attempted to run a binomial logistic regression with temperature (factor: 5 levels 20, 23, 26, 29 and 32 degrees Celsius), species (factor: 2 levels HA and AP) and the interaction between them as independent variables. The dependent variable is the proportion of eggs that hatched. Here is my model and model output:

```
eggmodelA <- glm(cbind(No.hatched,No.eggs.added-No.hatched) ~ Temperature * Species, data=eggto1st, family = binomial(link="logit"))
summary(eggmodelA)
```

```
Call:
glm(formula = cbind(No.hatched, No.eggs.added - No.hatched) ~ 
    Temperature * Species, family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
    data = eggto1st)

Deviance Residuals: 
 [1]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0

Coefficients:
                          Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                 0.6665     0.2822   2.361  0.01821 *  
Temperature23               1.3650     0.4702   2.903  0.00369 ** 
Temperature26              -0.7962     0.3295  -2.416  0.01567 *  
Temperature29              -0.3427     0.3240  -1.058  0.29026    
Temperature32              -1.4026     0.3250  -4.316 1.59e-05 ***
Temperature35             -28.3452 51586.1741  -0.001  0.99956    
SpeciesHA                   0.7423     0.4391   1.691  0.09092 .  
Temperature23:SpeciesHA    -1.8376     0.6354  -2.892  0.00383 ** 
Temperature26:SpeciesHA     0.3990     0.5027   0.794  0.42735    
Temperature29:SpeciesHA    -1.0553     0.4896  -2.155  0.03115 *  
Temperature32:SpeciesHA    -1.3219     0.4976  -2.657  0.00789 ** 
Temperature35:SpeciesHA    -0.4598 73007.1005   0.000  0.99999    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 5.5111e+02  on 11  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 5.5220e-10  on  0  degrees of freedom
AIC: 73.512

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 22
```

I also ran a likelihood ratio test which showed the interaction between species and temperature to be significant:

```
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model 1: cbind(No.hatched, No.eggs.added - No.hatched) ~ Temperature * 
    Species
Model 2: cbind(No.hatched, No.eggs.added - No.hatched) ~ Temperature + 
    Species
  Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance  Pr(>Chi)    
1         0        0.0                          
2         4     5520.1 -4  -5520.1 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

This led me to plot the interaction using the emmip() function in the package emmeans and conduct pairwise comparisons between species (within each temperature) and between temperatures (within each species). The results for the between temperature comparisons are as follows:

```
#Effect of temperature
Within.species<-emmeans(eggmodelA, pairwise ~ Temperature|Species)
emmeans:::cld.emmGrid(Within.species$emmeans, Letter = letters, alpha = 0.05)
```

```
Species = AP:
 Temperature  prob     SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL .group
 32          0.324 0.0353 Inf     0.259     0.396  a    
 26          0.468 0.0423 Inf     0.386     0.551  ab   
 29          0.580 0.0388 Inf     0.503     0.654   b   
 20          0.661 0.0633 Inf     0.528     0.772   b   
 23          0.884 0.0385 Inf     0.785     0.941    c  

Species = HA:
 Temperature  prob     SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL .group
 32          0.212 0.0283 Inf     0.161     0.272  a    
 29          0.503 0.0368 Inf     0.431     0.574   b   
 23          0.718 0.0534 Inf     0.603     0.810    c  
 26          0.733 0.0344 Inf     0.661     0.795    c  
 20          0.804 0.0531 Inf     0.679     0.888    c  

Confidence level used: 0.95 
Intervals are back-transformed from the logit scale 
P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 5 estimates 
Tests are performed on the log odds ratio scale 
significance level used: alpha = 0.05
```

Would anyone be able to tell me how should I report the results of this analysis. Which parameters should I include and are there any that I am missing that I would need to report these results properly? Also, do I need to report the results for the main effects if the interaction is significant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `summary()` shows `Temperature35` values, while you don't show that temperature in your list in the text of the question. I'm assuming that your final model doesn't include the `Temperature35` data, which seem to be extreme (perhaps no hatches at all).

Instead of (or in addition to) the likelihood-ratio comparison of the model with and without the interaction term, you might consider showing an appropriate analysis of variance for the model with the interaction. That will evaluate the overall significance of the entire set of `Temperature` values and the `Species`, taking into account their interactions. You should use something like the "Type II" default of the `Anova()` function of the [`car` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=car), as the results of "Type I" analysis provided by the basic R `anova()` function depend on the order of variable entry into your model when data aren't balanced.

I'm not sure that the pairwise comparisons of all `Temperature` values within each `Species` is the best way to display your results. Although that's important to document which particular `Temperature` values can be distinguished statistically, the tables you show rank-order the categorical `Temperature` values by increasing estimates of probability of hatching within each `Species`. Show a plot of hatching probability against `Temperature` for each of the 2 `Species`, with confidence limits, to summarize your results simply. You might annotate that plot to incorporate the results of the pairwise comparisons.